# Difference between 'cat < file.txt' and 'echo < file.txt'

Tags: io-redirection, cat, echo

I have a file named file.txt which has some content say 'abcdef', when I do `cat < file.txt` I get the output abcdef but when I do `echo < file.txt`, no output is returned. Why doesn't the input redirection work with echo but works with cat?

Comment: What output did you expect from `echo < file.txt`?  Input redirection works just fine, it's just that `echo` doesn't try to read anything from `stdin`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Sorry, didn't know, thanks for help..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `echo` to read the `file.txt`( not to redirect ) as follows:

```
echo "$(<file.txt)"
```

Sample output :

```
abcdef
```

Comment: To split hairs, echo is still not reading the file; the shell is.

Comment: @Jeff, technically, the shell is reading the file, stripping the trailing newline characters (potentially choking on NUL bytes and invalid characters depending on the implementation) and passing that as an argument to `echo` which in turn may treat it as an option, expand sequences or choke on it  if it's too large.

Answer (score 11):

> Why doesn't the input redirection work with `echo` but works with `cat`?

Because the `echo` command doesn't accept anything from stdin like `cat` does, it accepts only parameters.

From `man cat`:

> cat - concatenate files and print on the standard output
>
> Synopsis
>
> cat [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>
> Description
>
> Concatenate FILE(s), or **standard input**, to standard output.

From `man echo`:

> echo - display a line of text
>
> Synopsis
>
> echo [SHORT-OPTION]... **[STRING]**...
>
> echo LONG-OPTION
>
> Description
>
> Echo the **STRING(s)** to standard output.

(emphasis mine)